# Found Packages Error en golang al tratar de correr una API

Tags: api, go, whatsapp

Hola gente como andan? espero que bien  !

Soy nuevo en golang y me descargue el proyecto de https://github.com/Rhymen/go-whatsapp , cree mi archivo main.go pero al querer ejecutarlo me aparece el siguiente error en pantalla :

"main.go:7:2: found packages whatsapp (chat_history.go) and main (main.go) in C:\Ryhmen Wsp "

Desde ya agradecidos por su ayuda gente !

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que decís, pareciera ser un tema en como esta configurado Go en el entorno o en el proyecto (depende de la version de Go que estés utilizando.)

Podrías dar un poco más de contexto?, version de Go, si configuraste el GOROOT, como inicializaste el proyecto en cuestión ( usas go-modules? ), etc.